# Windows SleepEx() doesn't resume when queueing an APC

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, apc

I have the problem that a thread that was sent to sleep using `SleepEx(INFINITE, true)` does not reliably continue when an APC is queued.

The application scenario is that software A must notice when software B has installed a certain Windows service.

For this, I create a new thread, register a callback function via `NotifyServiceStatusChange()`, and put the thread to sleep via `SleepEx(INFINITE, true)`.

If, during the runtime of software A, the specified service is installed, the callback function is called, the thread is continued, and finishes its `run()` method. Everything works fine.

But, if software A terminates without the callback function being called, I still want the thread to terminate properly.

The Microsoft documentation states this about the `SleepEx` function:

> Execution resumes when one of the following occurs:
>
> - An I/O completion callback function is called.
> - An asynchronous procedure call (APC) is queued to the thread.
> - The time-out interval elapses.

Therefore, I queue an APC to my thread using `QueueUserAPC()`. This works fine, my function `stopSleeping()` is called and executed: A breakpoint can be reached and debug output can be made inside this function.

Unfortunately, contrary to my expectation, my own APC does not cause the thread to resume running, as the call of the function `callback()` does.

The question is, why not?

My thread is a class derived from `QThread` and the `stopThread()` method is triggered by a SIGNAL/SLOT connection from the main thread.

```
// **********************************************
void CCheckForService::run()
{
   SC_HANDLE SCHandle = ::OpenSCManager( 0
                                       , SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE
                                       , SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE
                                       );
   if ( 0 != SCHandle )
   {
      meStatus = Status::BEFORE_NOTIFY_SVC_CHANGE;

      SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp;

      char    text[] = "MyServiceToLookFor";
      wchar_t wtext[ 20 ];
      mbstowcs( wtext, text, strlen( text ) + 1 );
      LPWSTR lpWText = wtext;    

      SERVICE_NOTIFY serviceNotify = { SERVICE_NOTIFY_STATUS_CHANGE
                                     , &CCheckForIIoT::callback
                                     , nullptr
                                     , 0
                                     , ssp
                                     , 0
                                     , lpWText
                                     };

      // Callback function is to be invoked if "MyServiceToLookFor" has been installed
      const DWORD result = ::NotifyServiceStatusChange( SCHandle
                                                      , SERVICE_NOTIFY_CREATED
                                                      , &serviceNotify
                                                      );

      if ( ERROR_SUCCESS == result )
      {
         meStatus = Status::WAITING_FOR_CALLBACK;
         ::SleepEx( INFINITE, true ); // Wait for the callback function
      }

      LocalFree( lpWText );
   }

   ::CloseServiceHandle( SCHandle );

   if ( Status::CANCELLED != meStatus )
   {
      // inform main thread
      emit sendReady( meStatus );
   }
}


// **********************************************
// [static]
void CCheckForService::stopSleeping( ULONG_PTR in )
{
   Q_UNUSED( in )

   meStatus = Status::CANCELLED;
}


// **********************************************
// [static]
void CCheckForService::callback( void* apParam )
{
   auto lpServiceNotify = static_cast< SERVICE_NOTIFY* >( apParam );

   // the service is now installed; now wait until it runs
   {
      QtServiceController lBrokerService( "MyServiceToLookFor" );

      QTime WaitTime;
      WaitTime.start();

      while ( !lBrokerService.isRunning() )
      {
         msleep( 1000 );

         //  Timeout check
         if ( WaitTime.elapsed() > WAIT_FOR_SERVICE_RUN * 1000 )
         {
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   meStatus = Status::OK;
}


// **********************************************
// [SLOT]
void CCheckForService::stopThread( void )
{

   HANDLE ThreadHandle( ::OpenThread( THREAD_ALL_ACCESS
                                    , true
                                    , ::GetCurrentThreadId()
                                    )
                      );

   DWORD d = ::QueueUserAPC( &CCheckForIIoT::stopSleeping
                           , ThreadHandle
                           , NULL
                           );

   ::CloseHandle( ThreadHandle );
}
```

Comment: Might you do better to use `WaitForSingleObject`?

Comment: `stopThread` from what thread called ? also not need `OpenThread` with `GetCurrentThreadId()`

Comment: @PaulSanders `WaitForSingleObject()` won't work in this case, since the service status callback is triggered via APC. `WaitForSingleObjectEx()` would work, though, if it has another object to wait on, like an Event object that `stopThread()` can signal. Or, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()` and just use `PostThreadMessage()` to wake it up, instead of creating a waitable object.

Comment: @RbMm: stopThread() is a Qt slot that is triggered by a signal emitted by the main thread when the software shuts down. Our main software is quite a large and complex application that shuts down all its different parts in several phases. Therefore, timing (the main software is shut down before the APC is processed) is not a problem.

Comment: Referring to the use of OpenThread: Microsoft documentation states that the handle used must have the THREAD_SET_CONTEXT access right when QueueUserAPC is called. Since I'm not too familiar with native Windows API programming, I wanted to make sure I was using a handle with the required permissions. But simplifying the code is always something I like very much. :)

Comment: @SoerenZimmermann - you post APC to main thread (to thread from which `stopThread` is called) but not to thread which what in `SleepEx` call. the answer of Turtlefight is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, given that you didn't provide a runnable example it's hard to verify.

My guess is that you're scheduling the APC on the main thread, instead of the `CCheckForService` thread.

If `CCheckForService::stopThread` is called from a signal/slot on the main thread, then it'll execute on the main thread.

So `::GetCurrentThreadId()` will return the thread id of the main thread, and you subsequently end up with calling `QueueUserAPC()` with a thread handle for the main thread, so the APC will execute on the main thread.

So the `CCheckForService` will remain sleeping, because it never received an APC.

You can verify this by comparing `QApplication::instance()->thread()` with `QThread::currentThread()` inside your `CCheckForService::stopSleeping` method - if they're equal you scheduled the APC on the main thread instead of the worker.

---

There's unfortunately no officially supported way in QT to get the thread id / thread handle of a `QThread`, apart from calling `QThread::currentThreadId()`.

So you'd have to store the thread id in your `CCheckForService` class, so you can later get the appropriate thread handle, e.g.:

```cpp
// TODO: Add to CCheckForService declaration
// private: DWORD runningThreadId;

// TODO: initialize runningThreadId in constructor to 0
// 0 is guaranteed to never be a valid thread id

void CCheckForService::run() {
    runningThreadId = ::GetCurrentThreadId();

    /** ... Rest of original run() ... **/
}

void CCheckForService::stopThread( void )
{
   HANDLE ThreadHandle( ::OpenThread( THREAD_ALL_ACCESS
                                    , true
                                    , runningThreadId /* <------ */
                                    )
                      );

   DWORD d = ::QueueUserAPC( &CCheckForIIoT::stopSleeping
                           , ThreadHandle
                           , NULL
                           );

   ::CloseHandle( ThreadHandle );
}
```

There's still a small race condition left in this example though - if you call `stopThread()` before the thread has started up & set the `runningThreadId`. In that case `OpenThread()` will fail and return `NULL`, so queuing the APC will fail.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my misconception. I assumed that my stopThread() method would be executed in the thread, but of course that is not the case, since the CCheckForService object was instantiated in the main thread.
The suggested solution of storing the thread ID in the run() method works perfectly.